# Core Data and display attributes from two entities (Many to Many) in Custom Cell

Tags: core-data, many-to-many, custom-cell

Not sure if it is possible, but I would like to list attribute info from two different entities that are many to many in one custom cell.  I read a similar question but didn't see a response. Trying to specify the gymnastNameText.text = score.gymnasts leads to error of cannot assign value of type NSSet? to type String?

```
class ScoreMeetCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var gymnastNameText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var barScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var barScoreText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var beamScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var beamScoreText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var floorScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var floorScoreText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var vaultScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var vaultScoreText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var allaroundScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var allaroundScoreText: UILabel!


    func configureScoreCell(score: Meet) {

        gymnastNameText.text = score.gymnasts


    }
```

Comment: You haven't explained your data model or what you're trying to show the user

Comment: Had 2 entities Gymnast and Meet (many to many).  If in my custom cell I call Meet, I cannot get the gymnast name in corresponding cell.  Now I have split scores into a new entity (one to many) from Gymnast to MeetResult.  Not sure what best approach is at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should have a model with a `Meet`, an `Attendance` and a `Gymnast`. The purpose of `Attendance` is to record details about the `Gymnast` specific to that particular `Meet` - i.e. the score attained.

So, `Meet` as a one-to-many to `Attendance`, and `Attendance` has a one-to-one with `Gymnast`.

Now, your view shows a list of `Attendance`, from which you know the `Gymnast` details and the score.